# What is the name of (and alternatives to) this Bayesian point-estimate?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, terminology

Assume that we have a Markovian environment that generates at every time step an event $A$ with probability $p^*$ and an event $B$ otherwise. Now suppose you are a Bayesian agent that wants to learn $p^*$ from the observations you've made so far. If we let our hypothesis class be $\{H_x\}_{0 \leq x \leq 1}$ and our initial prior be the uniform distribution ($f_0(x) = 1$), then according to Bayes rule we will update at each time step as:

$$
f_{t+1} = \begin{cases} 
\frac{x f_t(x)}{\int_0^1 x f_t(x) dx} & \text{if we saw A} \\
\frac{(1 - x) f_t(x)}{\int_0^1 (1 - x) f_t(x) dx} & \text{if we saw B}
\end{cases}
$$

The best estimate (at time $t$) $p_t$ for $p^*$ will then be the mean of $f_t$. [I can show](http://egtheory.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/subjective-bayes/) that tracking $p_t$ reduces to counting, in the sense that if by time $t$ you saw $a$ many $A$ events and $b = t - a$ many $B$ events then

$$p_t = \frac{a + 1}{(a + 1) + (b + 1)}$$

This seems like a basic result I would have seen in an introductory statistics course (which I unfortunately do not have). **What is this called?** If an agent was using the above procedure to estimate $p^*$ what kind of inference, regression, or estimation would they be doing?

Further, to make the answer not just a one-liner. **What are some alternatives?** In particular, what kind of assumptions would I need to make to have $p_t = \frac{a}{a + b}$? I.e. how can I eliminate  the uniformity bias caused by my choice of prior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The best estimate*? *Best* is subjective in Bayesian inference. It can be shown that using the mean of $f_t$, as you have, is the best estimate in the expected squared error sense, i.e. it minimizes $E_{f_t}[(p_t - p^*)^2]$. The function $L(p_t, p^*) = (p_t - p^*)^2$ is the squared error *loss function*. But others can be considered:

- $L(p_t, p^*) = | p_t - p^* |$, and here $E_{f_t}[ L(p_t, p^*) ]$ is minimized by not the mean of the posterior, but the *median* of the posterior.

In general, the solution to the problem:

$$ \arg \min_{p_t} E_{f_t}[ L(p_t, p^*) ] $$ 
is called the *Bayes action.*

You can choose a Loss that accurate reflects your desires: maybe you want to bias slightly towards 0,1 end points, so you could choose the loss
$$ L( p_t, p^*) = \frac{ (p_t - p^*)^2 }{ p_t(1-p_t) }$$

(Perhaps this fits into your *rationality* (or *irrationality*) model better as humans like to bias towards certainty as opposed to uncertainity). The Bayes action for this loss function would require more effort to calculate though.

[Here is a good manuscript](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~brani/isyebayes/bank/handout4.pdf)  that explains Bayes actions and loss functions quite well.

#### The estimate $\frac{a}{a+b}$

The estimate you proposed actually has a very simple solution. That solution is the maximum likelihood estimator of $p^*$ which is equivilant to choosing a uniform prior (like you have) and choosing the *maximum a-posterior* estimate (the MAP estimate), defined as the arg max of the posterior. (see page 2 in the paper linked).

Comment: Thank you! Would the estimate I gave be an MLE?

Comment: It would, but as I mentioned, you can derived the same estimate in Bayesian inference. The interpretation is different of course.

Answer (score 0):

The Jeffreys' minimum informative prior for this case is a Beta(1/2,1/2) (it has a U shape in [0,1], not flat).

The posterior distribution for p* is a Beta(1/2+a,1/2+b)

You can search in the wikipedia for:

- [Prior_probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability)
- [Beta_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)
- [Jeffreys_prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior)